# How can I encrypt / decrypt strings on multiple computers using the same key?

Tags: vb.net, .net-core

I need advice to make sure I do this correctly and securely. I have the need to encrypt strings such as my connection string to my database and decrypt it on the computers running the app. This executable for my app is located and executed by domain computers from a network share.

How can I have the client decrypt my strings without anybody seeing my decryption key? I did create a certificate on my domain CA with a private key. I was able to import this certificate onto my PC and use it to encrypt and decrypt but then I realized if anybody just runs my decrypt code on a pc that has the certificate installed they could easily get the clear text?

Here is my current code for encrypting and decrypting:

```
Public Class Certificates

    Private Shared Function FindCert(ByVal certificateName As String) As X509Certificate2
        Dim store As X509Store = New X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine)
        store.Open(OpenFlags.[ReadOnly])
        For Each currentCertificate As X509Certificate2 In store.Certificates
            If currentCertificate.FriendlyName.Equals(certificateName) Then Return currentCertificate
        Next
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Public Shared Function Encrypt(ByVal stringToEncrypt As String) As String
        Dim x509 = FindCert("certname")

        If x509 Is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToEncrypt) Then
            RadMessageBox.Show(Nothing, "Could not find the certificate!", "Certificate Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, RadMessageIcon.Error)
            End
        End If

        Dim rsa As RSACng = CType(x509.GetRSAPublicKey, RSACng)
        Dim bytestoEncrypt As Byte() = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt)
        Dim encryptedBytes As Byte() = rsa.Encrypt(bytestoEncrypt, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256)
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes)

    End Function

    Public Shared Function Decrypt(ByVal stringTodecrypt As String) As String
        Dim x509 = FindCert("certname")

        If x509 Is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringTodecrypt) Then
            RadMessageBox.Show(Nothing, "Could not find the certificate!", "Certificate Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, RadMessageIcon.Error)
            End
        End If

        If Not x509.HasPrivateKey Then Throw New Exception("x509 certicate does not contain a private key for decryption")
        Dim rsa As RSACng = CType(x509.GetRSAPrivateKey, RSACng)
        Dim bytestodecrypt As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(stringTodecrypt)
        Dim plainbytes As Byte() = rsa.Decrypt(bytestodecrypt, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256)
        Dim enc As System.Text.ASCIIEncoding = New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding()
        Return enc.GetString(plainbytes)

    End Function
```

Comment: Ok, so this is a really big topic, and can be quite divisive hence why I'm not answering.  1st suggestion I would make is don't try encrypting connection strings.  Use AD/Windows authentication to your DB server if possible.  That way at least if security is comprinised, it's the either the end user or sysadmin at fault :)

Comment: Next thing, if someone is dedicated enough to pull apart your program and run you decrypt code to inspect the values, probably find they are dedicated enough just to find any number of alternative ways to compromise security.

Comment: Not trying to say what you're doing is wrong or anything and should be some security for sure, just trying to make the point that it can actually be quite a investment, just potentially very little benefit

Comment: Yes after chewing on this for hours I don't think it is possible to do what I am trying to do.  The real issue is I need to store credentials which have elevated rights in AD so the users can run processes they usually don't have the rights to run. I am trying to avoid delegating accounts in AD.